# English for Ireland

Tags: language

I am not sure is it a proper place to ask this question but I was not able to find more suitable SE site. If you can move it in a proper site it will be nice.

My [website](http://www.tiksn.com) supports US and UK English. I want to enhance *English dialects or versions* and add **Irish English**. Is it a good practice to add *Irish English* to website? Is it actually a first language of Ireland as it told in most sites of Internet?

Comment: While I applaud your attempt at cultural sensitivity at that level, from a UX POV, I question the value of offering variations of the same language--assuming that most people that know one of these variations can easily read the others.

Comment: Date format, currency, and other stuff is going to be in Irish culture.

Comment: Instead of having a person have to choose a language, perhaps choose a universal date format and consider showing prices in all currencies?

Comment: The formal standard English dialect of Ireland is virtually indistinguishable from that spoken throughout the UK. I wonder if you are not confusing this with the informal, spoken English dialect(s) or perhaps Irish Gaelic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_written_English
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_language

Comment: I think this belongs on http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DannyVarod It is more about Ireland and UX rather than English

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually live in Ireland so I can tell you first hand that **UK English is OK** for us for the topics of your website. There are some differences in everyday speech but not in technology jargon etc. Even these differences are nothing major and you'll find many UK newspapers in circulation or series on the TV.

I think it would add more value to a website's UX to offer articles in more [common languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers) rather than English dialects.

Comment: +1. Just to add, as another Irish user, I've the regional setting on my Mac set to English (Ireland). The only difference I can see is that it will default the currency to Euro rather than Sterling. It seems to apply more as a region than a language setting in this case. So possibly, if your site had additional features (e.g. shopping basket) you may want a regional setting for things like currency and postcode formats (we have none, don't make it required! :) ), but otherwise a standard English setting should be fine for purely linguistitc purposes.

Comment: Thank you guys, now I know that I will add *English (Ireland)* culture to my website.

Comment: Already added English (Ireland). Thanks for your advice.